# Call methods with sililar names through a loop in geb

Tags: selenium, geb

I'm new to Geb and fairly new in Java. I ask my self if its possible to call multiple methods through a loop. For example this part:

```
homePage.file1 = Content.Upload()
isDisplayed(homePage.clear1, true)
homePage.file2 = Content.Upload()
isDisplayed(homePage.clear2, true)
homePage.file3 = Content.Upload()
isDisplayed(homePage.clear3, true)
```

I had the idea to call this through a loop cause the names are very similar to each other. Only the numbers are different.
So I thought about something like this:

```
String[] elements = { "file1", "file2","file3"}
for( int i = 0; i <= elements.length - 1; i++){
    homePage.elements[i] = Generator.fileUpload()
}
```

But this won't work. Is there any other way to get this to work?

Greetings

Comment: What is your error?

Comment: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: Unable to resolve elements as content for com.**********.pages.HomePage, or as a property on its Navigator context. Is elements a class you forgot to import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think this is what you're trying to achieve?:

```
def elements = ["file1", "file2","file3"]
elements.each {     
    homePage."${it}" = Generator.fileUpload()
}
```

Comment: thank you dude! That's exactly what I've looked for. Works perfect